# Publishing service with Sitemap XML

Tags: publishing-service, sitemap

I've got the Sitemap XML package installed and I'm interested in using the new publishing service. Because the publish:end pipeline is no longer used with the publishing service, where would I put that call for the Sitemap XML now so it fires after the publishing service runs?

Comment: Which version of the publishing service are you using? I thought the latest one (2.0) does have the publish:end event.

Comment: I'm not using it yet, just been doing some reading. I just know it doesn't use the "classic" publish:end pipeline, or I thought it didn't at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v2.0, the publishing service module exposes a new event in Sitecore: `publishingservice:publishend`

When the publishing service completes a publishing job, this event is triggered once for the entire job in addition to the three events from the existing publishing system:

- `publish:begin`
- `publish:complete`
- `publish:fail`

So apparently the `publish:end` is not yet supported but you could use the new event from the service or the publish:complete.
I tested that last one and it works, but has a small bug: the published languages are not all send to the event (just the first one). That has been fixed in a hotfix though (can give the number as soon as I can access the support site again).

Be aware that the arguments for the events are not the same, so you will need to write the event code again.